# Pandas: filling missing values by weighted average in each group

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, weighted-average

I have a dataFrame where 'value'column has missing values. I'd like to filling missing values by weighted average within each 'name' group. There was post on how to fill the missing values by simple average in each group but not weighted average. Thanks a lot!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, np.nan, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, np.nan, np.nan],'weight':[3,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1], 'name': ['A','A', 'A','B','B','B', 'C','C','C']})


   name  value  weight
0    A    1.0       3
1    A    NaN       1
2    A    3.0       1
3    B    2.0       2
4    B    3.0       1
5    B    1.0       2
6    C    3.0       2
7    C    NaN       1
8    C    NaN       1
```

I'd like to fill in "NaN" with weighted value in each "name" group, i.e.

```
   name  value  weight
0    A    1.0       3
1    A    1.5       1
2    A    3.0       1
3    B    2.0       2
4    B    3.0       1
5    B    1.0       2
6    C    3.0       2
7    C    3.0       1
8    C    3.0       1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group data frame by `name`, and use `fillna` method to fill the missing values with weighted average which can calculated with `np.average` with `weights` parameter:

```
df['value'] = (df.groupby('name', group_keys=False)
                 .apply(lambda g: g.value.fillna(np.average(g.dropna().value, weights=g.dropna().weight))))

df
#name   value   weight
#0  A    1.0    3
#1  A    1.5    1
#2  A    3.0    1
#3  B    2.0    2
#4  B    3.0    1
#5  B    1.0    2
#6  C    3.0    2
#7  C    3.0    1
#8  C    3.0    1
```

---

To make this less convoluted, define a *fillValue* function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def fillValue(g):
    gNotNull = g.dropna()
    wtAvg = np.average(gNotNull.value, weights=gNotNull.weight)
    return g.value.fillna(wtAvg)

df['value'] = df.groupby('name', group_keys=False).apply(fillValue)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I was trying to use transform and get nowhere.

Comment: Normally you can use transform if the calculation only involves one single column, but you are calculating weighted averages here. So you need apply to access more than one column.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Pretty new to python, so lots to pick up. Thanks!